# connect to oracledb in java

Tags: java, database, oracle, dsn

I work in a big company and need to connect to a oracle database. It is set up so that i can connect to it through DSN, but I would like to connect to the db directly. How do i do that, when the only information I have is the name of the db and the username and password. It works fine through dsn.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793408/how-can-i-connect-to-a-web-based-oracle-database-with-java

Answer (score 1):

Most the Java developers I know use JDBC Thin Client to connect. You need user/pass, hostname and database id and you should be able to connect.